# Error: Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind

Tags: java, serversocket

When I used

```
 InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.104");
 listen_socket = new ServerSocket(port,5,addr);
```

then it works fine

But when use dynamic ip

```
  InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("114.143.95.69");
  listen_socket = new ServerSocket(port,5,addr);
```

the following error will be thrown

> Error: Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind

What should I do to resolve the problem?

Comment: Bind to 0.0.0.0 instead.

Comment: thats means already some other process is active on passed port. Kill that process and retry.

Comment: @pramod.nikam,dev Not unless the message contains the words 'already in use'.

Answer (score 2):

Your dynamic IP is the address of your router, not an IP address belonging to an NIC of the localhost.

Use "0.0.0.0", or a null InetAddress, for that parameter.